# Paperclip gem don't shows pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have successfully installed Paperclip gem and uploaded a picture to my post, but in show action there isn't any picture, just alt text with image alt.

I am using ruby on rails 3.2.1

**@post form:**

```
<% create_url = {:url=>{:action=>"create"}} if @post.new_record? %>
      <% form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |t| %>
        <b><%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %></b><br />
        <%= t.text_field :title %><br /><br />
        <b><%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %></b><br />
        <%= t.text_area :content %><br /><br />
        <%= f.file_field :bildes %>
<div class="actions">
  <%= t.submit %>
</div>
```

**@post show:**

```
 <p><%= @post.content  %></p>
 <%= image_tag @post.bildes.url %>
 <%= image_tag @post.bildes.url(:medium) %>
 <%= image_tag @post.bildes.url(:thumb) %>
```

In my opinion @post model url and path is not right, but exactly what I don't know.

**@post model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :bildes, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                    :url => ":rails_root/app/assets/bildes/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/bildes/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the default url/path for the attached file by not specifying it in the model.

Comment: Yes, I was right! Problem is in my url and with your help now I know this. Thanks! But how I can make the right url?

Comment: First place I would look into is paperclip wiki :)

Comment: I am doing this, but every time I miss something. Anyway thank you! :)